# When labeling dimension is too big and want to find another way rather than one-hot encoding

Tags: machine-learning, encoding, neural-network, one-hot-encoding

I am a beginner who learns machine learning.

I try to make some model(FNN) and this model has too many output labels to use a one-hot encoding.

Could you help me?

I want to solve this problem :
labeling data is for fruits:

Type (Apple, Grapes, Peach), Quality(Good, Normal, Bad), Price(Expensive, Normal, Cheap), Size(Big, Normal, Small)

So, If I make one-hot encoding, the data size up to 3*3*3*3, 81

I think that the labeling data looks like 4 one-hot-encoding sequence data.

Is there any way to make labeling data in small-dimension, not 81 dimension one hot encoding?

I think binary encoding also can be used, but recognized some shortcoming to use binary encoding in NN.

Thanks :D

Comment: encode individual categories separately and merge them together at the end to form the combined data frame

Comment: i think if the data is feature data, then it has no problem. but if label for output data(result data) then has some problem....  is it okay to just encode individual for output data?

Comment: Yes. Then eventually it becomes multi class classification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you one hot encode your 4 variables you will have 3+3+3+3=12 variables, not 81.

The concept is that you need to create a binary variable for every category in a categorical feature, not one for every possible combination of categories in the four features.

Nevertheless, other possible approaches are Numerical Encoding, Binary Encoding (as you mentioned), or Frequency Encoding (change every category with its frequency in the dataset). The results often depend on the problem, so try different approaches and see what best fits yours!

Comment: Thanks! i try to consider other encodings. but I am still confused about the encoding dimension. I want to make label for output data. so if i use one-hot encoding for each category, is it just binary encoding? becus it is not one hot. Confused..

Answer (score 0):

But even if you use One-Hot-Encoding, as @DavideDn pointed out, you will have 12 features, not 81, which isn't a concerning number.
However, let's say the number was indeed 81, you could still use dimensionality reduction techniques (like Principal Component Analysis) to solve the problem.

Comment: I want to label for output data. If i use one-hot encoding individually then, is it just binary encoding? not one-hot encoding.. Thanks!